# Redirect output and save to remote server?

Tags: command-line, networking, netcat, tcpdump

Is it at all possible to redirect some stdout and have the data saved to a file on a remote server? Below is a terrible example the definitely don't work...

```
sudo tcpdump ... 2>&1 | ssh ... user@hostname -
```

Or perhaps using netcat instead of SSH?

```
sudo tcpdump ... 2>&1 | nc <host> <port> -
```

[Something like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7939023/netcat-is-there-a-way-to-send-a-continuous-stream-from-a-command-output-to-a-r) but the solution doesn't work for me..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, if you use a command with ssh that writes to the file:

```
sudo tcpdump ... 2>&1 | ssh ... user@hostname tee /some/file
sudo tcpdump ... 2>&1 | ssh ... user@hostname 'cat > /some/file'
```

With `nc`, you'd have to have something on the server listening:

```
# on server
nc -l <port> > /some/file
# on client
sudo tcpdump ... 2>&1 | nc <host> <port>
```

Comment: Yeah, I tried that exact tcpdump/nc usage. There's no output on the server side. The /some/file is always empty after generate GET requests on the client side

Comment: Then you'd have to check where tcpdump is sending its output to. You can swap `sudo tcpdump` with some other command, say `echo foo` to test that `nc` is working fine.

Comment: echoing foo works, i received it on the server. how can i debug using tcpdump? does piping tcpdump work for you?

Comment: using tcpdump alone and generating traffic, i can see data in the tcpdump terminal. im not sure why its not working with nc...

Comment: Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/25604237/2072269